# rnorm function in R - Usage

Tags: r

I understand the normal usage of rnorm (pardon the pun)

```
rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 1)
```

However, I came across the code below and I am not sure what the 2nd input array does as the mean.

```
y <- rnorm(12, rep(c(1,2,1), each=4),0.2)
```

(from R. Peng's Exploratory Data Analysis with R, pg 99)

Comment: `rep(c(1,2,1), each=4)` repeats 1, 2, and 1 four times each. Then `rnorm` is producing (pseudo-)random numbers from normal distributions with means of 1, 2, and 1 and standard deviations of 0.2. To make this obvious, do `rnorm(6, rep(c(1,20,100), each=2),0.2)`.

Comment: If you change it to `rep(c(1,200,1), ...`, you should see what is happening. Long-story-short: arguments can be a single value (repeated for all of `n`) or a vector of values, recycled if not as long as `n` defines.

Comment: so in essence, is this equivalent to   c(rnorm(1,1,0.2), rnorm(1,2,0.2), rnorm(1,1,0.2), .......,rnorm(1,1,0.2))  (array of 12) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
y <- rnorm(12, rep(c(1,2,1), each=4),0.2)
```

I can break this down as follows:

1. Generate 4 normal random variables with mean 1 and sd=0.2
2. Generate 4 normal random variables with mean 2 and sd=0.2
3. Generate 4 normal random variables with mean 1 and sd=0.2

Instead of writing a for loop or on different codes, You can do this all in one line.. That is the sweetness of R.

That is the code you have above. All the three statements in one line.